# Java threads summing single value

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, addition

In Java, why in the code below `synchronized` can be commented? Because addition happens to be nearly atomic and thus the probability of error or failure is too small?

```
public class AddInParallel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        class sumValue {
            public int sum = 0;
            sumValue() {}
            public /*synchronized*/ void add(int i) {
                sum += i;
            }
        }

        // final makes sumValue visible to threads
        final sumValue sum = new sumValue();

        class Adder implements Runnable {

            // used to distinguish threads
            private int id;

            Adder(int index) { id = index; }

            public void run() { sum.add(1); }

        }    

        // start threads
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[1000];
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
            threads[i] = new Thread(new Adder(i) {});
            threads[i].start();
        }

        // wait for threads above to finish
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
            try {
                threads[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println(sum.sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: It'll appear that way but it isn't. Try just adding 1, 1000 times. You'll see the result being around 998 or 997, not 1000 like you'd expect.

Comment: If in each thread I will add 1 1000 times, the result will be 1000 * #threads = 1000000. True, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Sotirios, if we change the code just here:

```
public /*synchronized*/ void add(int i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
        sum += i;
    }
}
```

it will not be usually a million in the end. So **synchronized** is required. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this kind of statement cannot be always considered as atomic:

```
sum += i;
```

Indeed, this one involves three steps (counting the temporary variable to store the current value of `sum`).

Even a `volatile` keyword on the `sum` variable declaration would not be relevant in this case (since assignment is based on its current value).

Therefore, you should uncomment the `synchronized` keyword to enable locking in order to not meet "surprises" in your process => meaning ending up always with `1000`.

Answer (score 0):

The `synchronized` keyword shouldn't be commented out. Any time you're writing to a variable from multiple threads, (at least) the write itself should be protected with some kind of synchronization -- the `synchronized` keyword, a [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html), etc. As you mention in your question, the reason for this is that individual writes are not guaranteed to be atomic.

While I suspect that the purpose of this code is prove a point, it's also worth noting that  you don't need to use a lock for this code; you could get a correct solution without using synchronization of any kind by using an `AtomicInteger` instead of an `int` for the `sum` variable.

Specifically, you could replace `public int sum` with `public AtomicInteger sum=new AtomicInteger();`, and the body of `add()` with:

```
public void add(int i) {
    sum.addAndGet(i);
}
```

...and you now have a lockless, correct implementation. (You'd have to update the code in a couple of other places to get printing and stuff up and running, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader. :)

Comment: What is the motivation to use `AtomicInteger` over `synchronized`? Is not it the same such that `AtomicInteger` in fact uses `synchronized` at the background?

Comment: Good question. It actually isn't the same. The [documentation for the java.util.concurrent.atomic package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) states that it is "A small toolkit of classes that support lock-free thread-safe programming on single variables."

These variables are intended for counters and such, which is a good fit for this use case. Being lockless, I suspect that these methods are using something like [Fetch-and-add instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetch-and-add) under the covers.

Comment: a later release of AtomicXXX classes will use an atomic increment instruction.  but as of now it uses a manual compareAndSet invocation.  For Sophie Sperner take a look intp CAS to see how the AtomicInteger is implemented, it does not use synchronized

Comment: John, looking at [the OpenJDK 7 implementation of AtomicInteger](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.java.html) indicates that you're correct: `addAndGet()` uses `compareAndSet()` in (at least) some implementations. However, since AtomicInteger is lockless, there must be a [read-modify-write instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-modify-write) somewhere in the mix. Apropos: the implementation of `compareAndSet()` references `sun.misc.Unsafe#compareAndSwapInt()`, which is (ostensibly) a thin wrapper around just such an instruction.